# Changing content and phone number on URL Parameter (Show Adwords visitor different phone number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am just starting to use Google Adwords, and I would like to know if I can put some type of cookie or redirect that shows a different phone number for my website if someone comes from Google Adwords, and then have the normal phone number for organic search.

For example,

If someone clicks my adwords url, they see the phone number 888-555-1111

If someone clicks through organic search they the phone number 800-111-2222

Is there a way to do this?

Here's a website that does this:
http://www.protectyourhome.com/

Here's my website:
http://www.securemyhome.com/

Thank you so much for your help.